# Python program works, but it shows an error. Why?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new in programming and I have done my research on this website and others, but I can't find anything helpful for my problem. I am writing a Python program with several PyQt windows opening when different buttons are pressed. This is my program:

```
import sys, os, 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
Ui_IntroWindow = uic.loadUiType('introduction.ui')[0]
Ui_ElmWindow = uic.loadUiType('elm.ui')[0]
Ui_ClueWindow = uic.loadUiType('pistaelm.ui') [0]
Ui_ButtonWindow = uic.loadUiType('firtsguibutton.ui')[0]

class IntroWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_IntroWindow):

    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.continuar.clicked.connect(self.continuar_clicked)

    def continuar_clicked(self):
        window = ElmWindow(self)
        window.show()
        window.exec_()
        self.close()

class ElmWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_ElmWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.bpista.clicked.connect(self.pista)
        self.bcontinuar.clicked.connect(self.continuar)


    def pista(self):
        pistaelm = ClueWindow(self)
        pistaelm.show()
        pistaelm.exec_()

    def continuar(self):
        elemento = str(self.elemento.text())
        main = ButtonWindow(self)
        if elemento == 'cobalto':
            main.show()
            main.exec_()
            self.close()         

class ClueWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_ClueWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class ButtonWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_ButtonWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = IntroWindow()
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have several sub windows created, for example in:

```
def continuar_clicked(self):
    window = ElmWindow(self)
    window.show()
    window.exec_()
    self.close()
```

If i don't write

```
window.exec_()
```

the window will open, but the buttons won't work. But when i write it I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Project\project.py", line 19, in continuar_clicked
    window.exec_()
AttributeError: 'ElmWindow' object has no attribute 'exec_'
```

How can I stop the error?

Comment: please debug your program to specify the part of code throwing error

Comment: sorry, but how do i debug the program? i've tried in idle and checking the module, but nothing has happened

Comment: There is probably more to the error message than that single line.  The entire error message provides information that will help debut it.

Comment: @bltrx. The error can be stopped by not calling non-existent methods, obviously. What does "the buttons won't work" mean? That is the only real issue here.

Comment: @ekhumoro if i don't call window.exec_() the next window will appear, but it wont work, everytime i click on its buttons (the ones i put there and wrote what they are supposed do), the window stops and i have to restart the program.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning for why you expect `window.exec_()` to be defined?

Comment: @Joel i don't expect it to be defined i was just trying to make it work so i tried that and then the program did and stil does exactly what i want it to do, that's why i am asking why it works even if it's not defined...

Comment: If that's your question, it's not clear from what you've written above.  At any rate Python doesn't check in advance whether something is defined.  It's perfectly happy to run and then, suddenly, you call `window.exec_()`.  So it tries to look it up.  But apparently, it was never defined.  So Python dies.  Languages like C++ will check in advance, which has benefits and downsides, but Python won't.  As for why the buttons won't work when it's not there:  what lines of your code tell it what to do when a button is clicked?

Comment: @bltrx. Please don't keep saying "it won't work". Describe what actually happens, and how that differs from what you expected to happen. (And get rid of all those useless `exec_()` calls before you test things again).

Comment: @Joel Okay, i am sorry if that wasn't clear. For example, the first window is IntroWindow. These were the lines that would tell what to do when a button was clicked:
    
    def continuar_clicked(self):
            window = ElmWindow(self)
            window.show()
            window.exec_()
            self.close()

Comment: @Joel And when the continuar button was clicked, ElmWindow would appear. That window has 2 buttons: pista and continuar. These are the lines that tell what to do when each of those buttons are clicked:

    def pista(self):
        pistaelm = ClueWindow(self)
        pistaelm.show()
        pistaelm.exec_()
          
    def continuar(self):
        elemento = str(self.elemento.text())
        main = ButtonWindow(self)
        if elemento == 'cobalto':
            main.show()
            main.exec_()
            self.close()
(i'm sorry that they are not idented)

Comment: @ekhumoro what actually happens is that when i run the program without exec_() the window is *not responding* whenever i press the buttons that i have already mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects derived from `QMainWindow` do not have a method `exec_()`. This is why you see the exception.

The reason this exception is modifying the behaviour of your program is because when an exception is raised, the rest of the slot currently being executed is not run. So your `continuar_clicked` method runs until it hits the line with the missing method, and stops.

This points to the fact that not calling `self.close()` in `continuar_clicked` keeps your GUI working. Calling `self.close()` is apparently breaking the program.

SO what does this mean? Well it points to a bad object hierarchy. You are spawning new windows, that are children of an existing window, and then **closing** the parent window. Quite possibly the parent window is being deleted, depending on whether the [`Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute is set to true for your windows.

So I would suggest redesigning your program. Perhaps have a parent window that is always open, or write a window managing class which handles the creation/closing of all windows (eg a window object calls a method from your window managing object to close the current window and open a new window).

Ultimately how you structure your code will be up to you as it is difficult to gauge the details of your program from a minimal example

Comment: A well-explained answer.